# How to create menu in UIKit

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, uilabel

I have been into cocos2d-iphone for ages, and today when I came back to UIKit, I totally forgot how to create menu in uikit. UIButton isn't really an option, a UILabel might sound good good.
What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use either an UISegmentedControl or an UIActionSheet. This will work if your menu will contain a few items.

Otherwise you can develop your own touch aware UIView and respond to user's selection as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For a selection from multiple (maybe many) items, use a UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0):

i think a simple UIButton with TypeCustom and no background would be sufficient and appropriate alternate for MenuItem of cocs2d-iphone. What do you say?